# Keeping git history during major restructuring of file contents

Tags: git, refactoring, structure

I am in the process of restructuring/refactoring a larger library, which means I need to re-categorize and re-order the existing functions. That includes moving around their code *within* files, but also *between* files.

Now I am a bit worried that this will mess up the project's git history. So my question is: Will it actually mess something up? If so, is there any way to prevent this?

At the moment it seems to me, that this process will be recognized by git as a whole lot of additions and deletions. Is that the correct way to go about it? Or would some un-orthodox methods like making smaller step-by-step commits help the task?

If somebody could give me some insight into this process, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with moving code between files; this will all be traceable with relative ease.  But renaming/moving entire _files_ is another story.  Do that, and you may mess up your Git history.

Answer (score 0):

History, in Git, *is* commits.  Or rather, the commits *are* the history.  That's it—that's all there is to it: keep the commits and you keep the history.  Use different commits and you have different history.  Add new commits, and you add new history.

> At the moment it seems to me, that this process will be recognized by git as a whole lot of additions and deletions.

Git does not store additions and deletions.  Each commit is a *complete snapshot*.  You identify a commit by its hash ID: `a234567...` or whatever.  This has every file that was in the index when you (or whoever) *made* that commit, as Git just makes commits by turning the index into a snapshot.

Each commit also has some list of parents, usually just one commit:

```
$ git log --first-parent
commit fd2fb4aa0cc2a25a8e4ddf3f3c48880f317edcf4
Author: ...
   [snip]

commit 4bdd6e7ce33c72dfaa79c4139d30bd809ec8eda7
Author: ...
   [snip]
```

Here the *parent* of commit `fd2fb4a...` is commit `4bdd6e7...`.  That's the *history*: `4bdd6e7` comes right before `fd2fb4a`, for instance.  So if you want to see what the author of `fd2fb4a` *changed*, you tell Git to *compare* the snapshot in `4bdd6e7`—the "before" picture—to the snapshot in `fd2fb4a`.

It's this *comparing* that produces additions and deletions.  (This comparing turns the commit into a *changeset* since some previous commit—usually, its immediate parent.)  The commits themselves, though, can stand alone.

If you want to find out what happened to some file, you instruct Git to look at each commit in sequence, to see what changed, but only *tell you* about that commit if that *one file* changed.  If you *rename* the file, well, now that one file that you told Git to look for has a different *name* and it is going to be looking for the wrong file.

The `git log` command has a flag, `--follow`, that attempts to work around this problem.  It looks at each parent/child pair and guesses which files were renamed.  If one of those files is the one file you told Git to look at, Git then *changes the one name that it's looking for*.  This process works best if the *only* change in the parent/child relationship is *just* the file renaming, but Git will make its best guess if you rename the file *and* change the content of the file, using its "similarity index" detector.  (This is slower and less accurate than just renaming and committing.)

This is, currently, all there is and all you can get.  It would be nice if Git could do a better job of following name-changes across multiple file names, but if you need that, you will have to write your own tools.